# Dataobject: GetFromClipboard OpenClipboard Failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel macro which transfers data from Excel to SQL. The macro copies the data to a text file and then I read the text file to upload it to Excel. The text file preserves the special characters while uploading via BCP.

The macro was working but now I get
[image]

Where the error occurs
[image]

```vb
Public Sub ExportSheetToSQL(Tabname As String, Filename As String, Tablename As String, firstRow As String)

'define variables
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long
Dim extnsion  As String

Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
Application.UseSystemSeparators = False

'get name of the workbook
CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
CurrentWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Name
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat

' Store current details for the workbook
SaveToDirectory = GetTempDirectory & "\"
extnsion = SaveToDirectory & Filename & ".txt"

'copy the workbook
'it is necessary to save it as an CVS file
Set CVSWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
With CVSWorkbook
    .Title = "CVS"
    .Subject = "CVS"
    .SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "XLS" & Filename & ".xls"
End With

Workbooks(CurrentWorkbookName).Activate
Worksheets(Tabname).Select
Worksheets(Tabname).Copy Before:=CVSWorkbook.Sheets(1)
'clear formats
'it is necessary to get rid of the USD format
'CVSWorkbook.Worksheets(Tabname).Range("A:XZ").ClearFormats

Dim lastRowIndex As Long
lastRowIndex = 0
lastRowIndex = Worksheets(Tabname).Range("A200000").End(xlUp).Row

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheet2.UsedRange.Copy
With GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    .GetFromClipboard
    CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").createtextfile(extnsion, True).Write .gettext
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False

TargetWorkbook = CVSWorkbook.FullName
' MsgBox TargetWorkbook

User = 'get active user here
CVSWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
   
'BCP UPLOAD CODE

End Sub
```

Comment: There's always the option of avoiding the issue entirely by not using the clipboard and outputting `Sheet2.UsedRange.Value` yourself. You could loop through the array and build a csv, or xml, or whatever format you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

**I was having the same issue** but in my case, the whole point is actually to keep the Clipboard available while changing the activeSheet (I have a macro running whenever I change the activeSheet and this messes up the Clipboard).

The original code (which was working some months ago):

```
Function GetTextFromClipBoard() As String
    
    Dim dataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim strText
    
    If Application.CutCopyMode > 0 Then
        dataObj.GetFromClipboard
        strText = dataObj.GetText()
        Debug.Print ("Text saved from Clipboard: '" & strText & "'")
    Else
        strText = ""
    End If
    GetTextFromClipBoard = strText

End Function
```

I noticed that I was able to continue after debugging without any change in the code, so **I kind of solved it for now** simply by trying again if there was an error. Of course this is not the best solution, but at least it's letting me continue working now...

```
Function GetTextFromClipBoard() As String

    Dim dataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim strText
    
    If Application.CutCopyMode > 0 Then
        On Error GoTo RETRY
RETRY:
        dataObj.GetFromClipboard
        strText = dataObj.GetText()
        On Error GoTo 0
        Debug.Print ("Text saved from Clipboard: '" & strText & "'")
    Else
        strText = ""
    End If

    GetTextFromClipBoard = strText

End Function
```